In nftables, why is port 443 traffic blocked only for non-web traffic?
I need to accept traffic on port 443, but nftables is currently accepting some traffic and blocking others, with no way to discern why.
This is a local client that is blocked at the client before it reaches the router/internet.
Here is the nftables log
Dec 26 19:01:56 carbon kernel: NFT: IP4 OUT FILTER LAN VPN - IN= OUT=tun0 SRC=10.35.163.13 DST=20.42.182.110 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=27048 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=48124 DPT=443 WINDOW=501 RES=0x00 ACK PSH FIN URGP=0 
Dec 26 19:09:02 carbon kernel: NFT: IP4 OUT FILTER LAN VPN - IN= OUT=tun0 SRC=10.35.163.13 DST=104.21.32.1 LEN=154 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=43481 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=54116 DPT=443 WINDOW=501 RES=0x00 ACK PSH FIN URGP=0
Dec 26 19:28:56 carbon kernel: NFT: IP4 OUT FILTER LAN VPN - IN= OUT=tun0 SRC=10.35.163.13 DST=20.42.182.110 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=27405 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=46420 DPT=443 WINDOW=501 RES=0x00 ACK FIN URGP=0

The prefix "NFT: IP4 OUT FILTER LAN VPN - " is found only once in one chain, so I know this is the chain blocking it.  it is called from other chains, but here is the initial hook too.
chain ip4_output_filter {
  type filter hook output priority filter
  policy drop
  [ ... ]
}

chain ip4_output_filter_lan_vpn {
  ip protocol { tcp, udp } th dport { $port_http, $port_https } ct state { new,established } counter accept
  [ ... ]
  counter log prefix "NFT: IP4 OUT FILTER LAN VPN - " drop
}

This is not web traffic, as i can view webpages fine.  here are all the accept packets when listing the table.
ip protocol { tcp, udp } th dport { 80, 443 } ct state { established, new } counter packets 34223 bytes 3341049 accept

This traffic happens when trying to log into a game server.  I don't know why it uses port 443.
How can I accept this traffic?
